# How to implement sqlite3_trace callback in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm having trouble implementing following callback from the sqlite3 api. Has someone a good example for implementing callbacks like this?

```
void *sqlite3_trace(sqlite3*, void(*xTrace)(void*,const char*), void*);
```

Found the solution:
(this goes before @implementation block)

```
void myCallbackFunc(void *foo, const char* bar) {
    NSLog(@"=> %s", bar);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, implement a function with the following signature:

```
void (*xTrace)(void*,const char*);
```

and then place a pointer to this function in the call to sqlite3_trace. The [sqlite3_trace page](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html) tells you what values will be passed to this function, so that you can NSLog then, [fs]printf them, show them on the screen, whatever you would like

Comment: The function has to return `void`, not `void*`.

Comment: Edited - shouldn't have been pointer to void, should be void pointer to function - sorry